# Performance problem when executing a function within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a performance, the screen freeze after a few clicks, problem when I run the following code snippet. To explain: I have a calendar that shows all days of a month. If I click on an arrow pointing to the right, the next month with all its days is displayed; if I click on the left button, exactly the other way around. I then render the code above for each day in an array. So every time you check again whether it is a holiday, as well as the formatting to a toLocaleDateString. Of course, this costs performance if I calculate this every time for 31 days. How can I simplify this or improve it completely?

```
//Is given date a 'Feiertag'?
const checkIfFeiertag = (dateToFilter) => {
return feiertage.filter(
  (isFeiertag) => isFeiertag.dateString === dateToFilter
 );
};


 {Array(days)
      .fill()
      .map((_, day) => {

        var newDate = new Date(
          date.getFullYear(),
          date.getMonth(),
          day + 1
        );

        const result = newDate.toLocaleDateString("sv-SE", {
          year: "numeric",
          month: "2-digit",
          day: "2-digit",
        });

        const checkResult = checkIfFeiertag(result);
    
       return (
          <div className="flex flex-col group p-1 " key={day}>

         ...
       )
  }
```

Comment: Why are you calculating `checkResult` if you never use it in your code? What is `feiertage`? In particular, how long is it?

Comment: Hard to tell without the full component. Check if any other state updates within the component cause unnecessary rerenders - memoize the array of dates so it's only rebuilt when the month changes.

Comment: Unless `feiertage` is a ***massively*** long array, I can't see how 31 iterations of that loop could cause a performance problem. I suspect the problem lies elsewhere. That said, `filter` has linear performance, it's not a good way to check if a value is in the array (not least because it doesn't stop when it's found a match). Instead, consider creating a `Set` from the array's `dateString` values, and using [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) on the `Set`, which is required to do better than linear performance.